# Postgres - determine the updated column names

Tags: postgresql

How we can determine what columns are being updated in postgres?

I'm tracking changes at the moment to do an "insert" or an "update", but my tables are so big and I want to track just specific columns.

I was thinking to use something like:

```
INSERT INTO track_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val, user_id, pg_user)
                    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD), CAST (NEW.updated_by AS INTEGER), CURRENT_USER );
```

But now I need to identify first if some of my columns (defined in another table) have been updated (or inserted).

But using "old_val" and "new_val" is there a way to find which columns are different?

**UPDATE**
My current trigger:

```
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
                INSERT INTO track_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, user_id, pg_user)
                    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), CAST (NEW.created_by AS INTEGER), CURRENT_USER );
                RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
                INSERT INTO track_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val, user_id, pg_user)
                    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD), CAST (NEW.updated_by AS INTEGER), CURRENT_USER );
                RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
                INSERT INTO track_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_val, user_id, pg_user)
                    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD), CAST (NEW.updated_by AS INTEGER), CURRENT_USER );
                RETURN OLD;
        END IF;
```

with that trigger you can register the changes for a complete record.
But now, I have the next table structure (I wasn't created by me)

```
tablename: config
id: PK Autogenerated INT
name: TEXT
value: TEXT
```

And an example of the data is this:

```
1   "track" "{ "tablename": ["column1", "column2"] }"
2   "track" "{ "article": ["title", "body"] }"
```

The issue is, before to insert it using the trigger I need to verify if one of the fields in my `config` table was modified

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of what you are doing now. Also pseudo code of what you want to add to process?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver updated!

Comment: You could create a [JSONB delete](https://github.com/glynastill/pg_jsonb_delete_op) function and then use the approach described here: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: That is a cool way of doing generic change tracking. @MrMins is looking for a solution that pulls out specific fields to track. I could see doing the '-' and then walking over the returned record to match fields coming from the ```config``` table.